# Passing generic class to amethod that returns a generic ObservableCollection of the same class that is passed

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, observablecollection

I am working with pulling data from a DB in WPF and doing it with multiple different tables, which I have modeled as POCO's in C#.  I want to be able to create a method that is flexible enough to handle any of these POCO's being passed in, and then return an observable collection of the same class to the caller.

I have something set up that I haven't tested yet, but I know this probably isn't the best way to implement this so I wanted to get some advice on how to best do this before I even bothered troubleshooting or attempting to get this to work:

```
 public static ObservableCollection<object> SQLAuthentication(ObservableCollection<object> myCollection, object myClass, String sql)
        {
            var conn = new SqlConnection();

            var paramList = GenerateSQLParameters(myClass, null);
            var tempModel = Global.GenerateNewInstance(myClass);

            //get the type
            Type model = tempModel.GetType();
            var prop = model.GetProperties();
            PropertyInfo pi;

            using (getConnection(conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd;
                SqlDataReader reader;

                cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    //set the values for each property in the model
                    foreach (var p in prop)
                    {
                        pi = tempModel.GetType().GetProperty(p.Name);
                        pi.SetValue(tempModel, reader[p.Name]);
                    }
                   myCollection.Add(tempModel);
                }
                reader.Close();
                cmd.Dispose();
            }

            return myCollection;
        }
```

Comment: That sounds like a XY problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Any reason why you're not just using Entity framework instead, or any other ORM

Comment: You could declare it as `public static ObservableCollection<T> SQLAuthentication(ObservableCollection<T> myCollection, T myClass, String sql) where T: class` .

Comment: @Aydin Adn  yes I would love to but unfortunately its a corporate project and we have no access to nuget.

Comment: @Christopher I'm not sure what you mean.  I want to be able to query any table in the DB generically and return the values for it.  Is there something else I should be asking?  Not trying to be a smart ass, just trying to understand what you are getting at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generic types in the method signature its self, you dont need to use object collection... and as im writing this John B hit the nail on its head

```
public static ObservableCollection<T> SQLAuthentication(ObservableCollection<T> myCollection, T myClass, String sql) where T: class
```

@John, if you post it as an answer ill remove this since you did technically shout it out first, just leave a comment if you do so i get the notification

Comment: Thanks! I had tried but forgot to add the T for myClass.  Just getting back into the awing of things in C#...I've been in mostly javascript/angular the past year and a half...

Comment: Actually this is almost correct but not fully.  It throws errors until you also put the <T> on the method call itself also:  public static ObservableCollection<T> SQLAuthentication<T>(ObservableCollection<T> myCollection, T myClass, String sql) where T: class  is what worked